# Recursive search within a directory for actionmailer preview

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I have a directory `bar` in `app/mailers` and a corresponding directory in `app/views`.

```
app/mailers
+-foo1_mailer.rb
+-foo2_mailer.rb
+-bar
  +-bar1_mailer.rb
  +-bar2_mailer.rb

app/views
+-foo1_mailer
| +-baz.text.erb
+-foo2_mailer
| +-...
+bar
  +-bar1_mailer
  | +-qux.text.erb
  +-bar2_mailer
    +-...
```

I am using action mailers' preview function with rspec.

I defined preview methods in files as so:

```
spec/mailers/previews
+-foo1_mailer_preview.rb
+-foo2_mailer_preview.rb
+-bar
  +-bar1_mailer_preview.rb
  +-bar2_mailer_preview.rb
```

By default, I can preview mails that are defined in a file under `app/mailers` like:

```
localhost:3000/rails/mailers/foo1_mailer/baz
```

I also want to preview files defined in a file under `app/mailers/bar` like:

```
localhost:3000/rails/mailers/bar/bar1_mailer/qux
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Did you create the mailers within the correct namespace? ie: `/bar/bar1_mailer/qux` defined in module `Bar::Bar1Mailer`?

Comment: @zwippie Yes. That is the case.